# Applet class is not loading in a JSP

Tags: javascript, java, swing, jsp, japplet

I'm working on maven web application with JSP and Servlets. I have a `href` which has a applet class call which loads my applet success fully from certain Servlet but on my windows only. Now I want to load this into client browser wherever this link is clicked from remote machine's IP. Please help me on this it should be loaded on client browser from HTML or JSP.

This is my class in my Java:

```
package com.enidiris.util;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AppletIris extends JApplet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean inAnApplet = true;

    public AppletIris() {
        this(true);
    }

    public AppletIris(boolean inAnApplet) {
        this.inAnApplet = inAnApplet;
        if (inAnApplet) {
            getRootPane().putClientProperty("defeatSystemEventQueueCheck", Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    public void init() {

        try {

            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createGUI();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void createGUI() {

        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

    }

}
```

This is my HTML in same web application but nothing says in console of browsers, not even loading applet.

webapp/ register.jsp

```html
<body onload="checkSession();">
    <jsp:plugin type="applet"  name="AppletIris" code="com.enidiris.util.AppletIris"  width="950"  height="650" hspace="0"  vspace="0" codebase="." >
        </jsp:plugin>
<!--     <object codetype="application/java" classid="java:AppletIris.class" -->
<!--    archive="enidiris-applet.jar" width="740" height="400"></object> -->
</body>
```

Comment: Applets are completely dead.

Comment: please help me or give me any solution

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: any other solutions to load applets in jsp ?